# Change Apache Directory

Tags: centos, apache-virtualhost

I am trying to change the /var/www/html default directory to /var/www/domain.com I have changed this in the httpd config file but it doesn't seem to work. I am running Centos 7 and Apache2

Comment: What is error you are getting?

Comment: cp: cannot stat ‘/etc/apache2/sites-available/default’: No such file or directory

Comment: I even tried changing the default to 000-default.conf and the same error

Comment: So then I went to /etc/ directory and there is no apache2 directory there? I don't know what is going on :(

Comment: What OS is it? try `locate apache2` that might help you.

Comment: So I am running Centos7 and I just installed mlocate and ran locate apache2 the error is "locate: can not stat () '/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db': No such file or directory"

Comment: I have installed Centos7, Apache2, MySQL and PHP. I am basically trying to get this up and running but it seems very difficult because of all the flavors of Linux. I might get the answer to some of my questions in one area but don't know if the are the correct answers to the installation that I am running

Comment: Ok so I just ran locate apache and got results /usr/sbin/apachect1 does that mean I only have apache 1 installed?

Comment: can you give me the status of these 2 commands `systemctl status firewalld` and `systemctl status iptables`

Comment: ● firewalld.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
[root@localhost /]# systemctl status iptables
● iptables.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Comment: I have not installed them yet

Comment: This is a basically a brand new setup

Comment: no need to install this. wanted to check if they are disabled to enable.

Comment: can you show me which rpm you have installed.

Comment: aic94xx-firmware-30-6.el7.noarch
centos-release-7-2.1511.el7.centos.2.10.x86_64
parted-3.1-23.el7.x86_64
filesystem-3.2-20.el7.x86_64
efibootmgr-0.8.0-7.el7.x86_64
kbd-misc-1.15.5-11.el7.noarch
linux-firmware-20150904-43.git6ebf5d5.el7.noarch
passwd-0.79-4.el7.x86_64
shim-0.9-2.el7.x86_64
e2fsprogs-1.42.9-7.el7.x86_64
libstdc++-4.8.5-4.el7.x86_64
tar-1.26-29.el7.x86_64
bash-4.2.46-19.el7.x86_64
iwl6000g2a-firmware-17.168.5.3-43.el7.noarch
iwl3945-firmware-15.32.2.9-43.el7.noarch
zlib-1.2.7-15.el7.x86_64
iwl3160-firmware-22.0.7.0-43.el7.noarch

Comment: audit-libs-2.4.1-5.el7.x86_64
iwl5000-firmware-8.83.5.1_1-43.el7.noarch
ivtv-firmware-20080701-26.el7.noarch
libcom_err-1.42.9-7.el7.x86_64
iwl2030-firmware-18.168.6.1-43.el7.noarch
iwl2000-firmware-18.168.6.1-43.el7.noarch
libdb-5.3.21-19.el7.x86_64
iwl1000-firmware-39.31.5.1-43.el7.noarch
bzip2-libs-1.0.6-13.el7.x86_64
iwl5150-firmware-8.24.2.2-43.el7.noarch
dbus-libs-1.6.12-13.el7.x86_64

Comment: gpg-pubkey-f4a80eb5-53a7ff4b
elfutils-libelf-0.163-3.el7.x86_64
apr-1.4.8-3.el7.x86_64
libffi-3.0.13-16.el7.x86_64
httpd-tools-2.4.6-40.el7.centos.1.x86_64
libacl-2.2.51-12.el7.x86_64
httpd-2.4.6-40.el7.centos.1.x86_64
libgcrypt-1.5.3-12.el7_1.1.x86_64
php-common-5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.x86_64
php-cli-5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.x86_64

Comment: p11-kit-0.20.7-3.el7.x86_64
php-mysql-5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.x86_64
sqlite-3.7.17-8.el7.x86_64
nss-softokn-freebl-3.16.2.3-14.2.el7_2.x86_64
diffutils-3.3-4.el7.x86_64
glibc-common-2.17-106.el7_2.6.x86_64
libcap-ng-0.7.5-4.el7.x86_64
nspr-4.11.0-1.el7_2.x86_64
file-libs-5.11-31.el7.x86_64
libuuid-2.23.2-26.el7_2.2.x86_64
pciutils-libs-3.2.1-4.el7.x86_64
nss-softokn-3.16.2.3-14.2.el7_2.x86_64
libassuan-2.1.0-3.el7.x86_64
chkconfig-1.3.61-5.el7_2.1.x86_64

Comment: e2fsprogs-libs-1.42.9-7.el7.x86_64
krb5-libs-1.13.2-12.el7_2.x86_64
libgomp-4.8.5-4.el7.x86_64
coreutils-8.22-15.el7_2.1.x86_64
xz-5.1.2-12alpha.el7.x86_64
libblkid-2.23.2-26.el7_2.2.x86_64
libnl3-3.2.21-10.el7.x86_64
systemd-219-19.el7_2.9.x86_64
newt-0.52.15-4.el7.x86_64
device-mapper-libs-1.02.107-5.el7_2.2.x86_64
lzo-2.06-8.el7.x86_64
device-mapper-event-libs-1.02.107-5.el7_2.2.x86_64
ethtool-3.15-2.el7.x86_64

Comment: This seems like a lot of information

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: There is a lot more

Comment: I meant for `apache2` which package you have installed. & always update the question.

Comment: I will check i am not sure

Comment: CentOS has httpd config files in `/etc/httpd`, not `/etc/apache2`. (And they may or may not provide the `sites-available` scheme.)

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please [edit] your question to add extra information. It is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments. Also, comments can be deleted with no warning.

Comment: You've read instructions for Ubuntu or Debian or any other derivative.  On RPM based systems, Apache goes by the name of `httpd`.  You'll therefore need to look in `/etc/httpd/conf' and `/etc/httpd.conf.d` for your Apache configs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As UlrichSchwartz commented, Debian/Ubuntu/etc uses package name apache2 with configuration in directory `/etc/apache2` while RedHat/CentOS/etc uses package name httpd and config directory `/etc/httpd`, and does not provide the `sites-enabled + a2ensite` scheme by default, although you can construct it if you want.

If you want to change the (by default only one) doc root, just edit `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`. If you want to set up virtual hosts, so that for example `http://example.com/` goes a different place (or places) than `http://localhost/`, then you get to decide whether you want to put them in the one config file, or split them out into several files in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` (note the dot dee). Often having each vhost in its own file is convenient, but this is by no means required.

PS: there is no Apache 1. `/usr/sbin/apachectl` is ctl as in charlie thomas lunatic, not one.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I will make the appropriate changes.